# Read text file line by line and store names into list in java

Tags: java, arraylist, file.readalllines

The task is to read the given file and return list of full names. I've separated the lines successfully and should be able to get both first and last names, but I'm a bit confused about how should I do that.

How am I able to get full names from `readData()`?

What I'm looking for is this output `["Alice Smith", "Bob Brown", "Carol White", "David Doe"]` and not duplicated names.

My code looks like this so far:

```
public class GradeRepository {

    public GradeRepository(){
        readData();
    }
    public void readData() {

        for (String line : readLines()) {

            String[] parts = line.split("\\|");

            String firstName = parts[0];
            String lastName = parts[1];
            String subject = parts[2];
            String grade = parts[3];

            System.out.println(firstName);
            System.out.println(lastName);
            System.out.println(subject);
            System.out.println(grade);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
        }

    }

    public List<String> getFullNames() {
        List<String> fullNames = new ArrayList<>();

        return fullNames;
    }

    private List<String> readLines() {
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("src/ex1/grades.txt"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Given text file:
grades.txt

```
Alice|Smith|math|5
Bob|Brown|english|4
David|Doe|math|3
Bob|Brown|math|4
Bob|Brown|chemistry|5
Alice|Smith|english|4
Carol|White|chemistry|3
David|Doe|chemistry|4
```

Comment: The best idea is create an Object maybe Person with field like firstName, lastName etc. anyway if you goal is return firstName + lastName you can return a Set<String> which will contains this information

Comment: Create a Set<String>. Put each name into the set.

Answer (score 0):

`readData` needs to be modified either to return a list of `String[]` where each string array represents a line or a field `List<String[]> data` needs to be created in `GradeRepository` and populated in `readData`.

Next, to get rid of duplicate names a `Set<String>` should be used as suggested in the comments, and `LinkedHashSet` implementation allows to keep the insertion order.

Example implementation where `readData` returns a list:

```java
public List<String[]> readData() {
    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line : readLines()) {
        String[] parts = line.split("\\|");
        // ... print parts as above if necessary...
        data.add(parts);
    }
    return data;    
}

public Set<String> getFullNames() {
    Set<String> fullNames = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (String[] row : readData()) {
        fullNames.add(row[0] + " " + row[1]);
    }

    return fullNames;
}
```

It may be more preferable to use Stream API to avoid creation of intermediate collections,  so all these methods may be rewritten into one:

```java
public Set<String> getFullNames() throws Exception {
    return Files.lines(Path.of("dataset.txt")) // Stream<String>
        .map(line -> line.split("\\|")) // Stream<String[]>
        .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1) // ensure there are 2 columns at least
        .map(arr -> arr[0] + " " + arr[1]) // Stream<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)); // get collection of unique names
}
```